# HP Pavilion dv5 boots with low brightness and graphics card not recognized

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

My problem is with Ubuntu 11.10 in my notebook hp pavilion dv5 with a graphic Intel(R) hd graphics. When I start Ubuntu my screen is without brightness, I can increase it with my control buttons, but when I restart I don't have brightness again. also Ubuntu doesn't recognize my graphic card (Intel HD (R) graphics), please i need your help because i like Ubuntu and i would like have it in my laptop (HP dv5 2045la) (3GB RAM) (500 GB DISK).

PS: I installed the repository MESA and now recognizes my card but my problem with the brightness

Comment: do you have a answer? please help me
pd sorry with my english, I'm from Peru and speak spanish, i try to  explain me well.

Comment: I would try Ubuntu 12.04 for one, for two, can you post the output from
lspci |grep -i vga

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!